# Tika information extraction

Tags: java, apache-tika

May I know how I can use Tika to extract information such as numbers in a tabular form in a web page? Does Tika have parsers to this end?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well You can extract web-pages in tika. For this purpose you can use `apache-tika's` `HTMLParser`. You will get everything you needed [here](http://tika.apache.org/)

Well you can also use `AutoDetectParser` which will `autodetect content type and extract content`. `AutoDetectParser` can detect any kind of file/url and will apply extraction.

> May I know how I can use Tika to extract information such as numbers in a tabular form in a web page?

--> Extracted content by tika is like a `raw` text. I don't think you will get it in Tabular form as it is.

Comment: Thanks. My question is that can I use tika to for example extract comment from youtube.com or is it just for extracting metadata?